# Not able to take the MongoDB backup/dump using node js

Tags: node.js, mongodb, windows, child-process, mongodump

When executing the written script, it exit with code 'one' while it should save the dump of the database

```js
const cron = require('node-cron');
const { exit } = require('process');
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

    let backupProcess = spawn('mongodump', [
        '--host=localhost',
        '--port=27017',
        '--out=.',
        '--db=testdb',
    ], {shell: true});

    backupProcess.on('exit', (code, signal) => {
        console.log('Function called');
        if(code) 
            console.log('Backup process exited with code ', code);
        else if (signal)
            console.error('Backup process was killed with singal ', signal);
        else 
            console.log('Successfully backedup the database')
    });
```

while executing the same through VS code terminal, getting following error,

```
Function called
Backup process exited with code  1 while should  save the dump at given location`your text`
```

Actual Result : `Backup process exited with code  1`

Expected result : Must dump the database

Comment: Does it work if you add the full path to `mongodump`?

Comment: No, it  doesn't work with full path as well